# How to get post category link in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Here is my code:
How to get category link, please let me know, I am getting this esc_url( category_link( $category->term_id ) ), is this right?

```
<?php printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br />',
    esc_url( category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
    esc_html( $category->name )
);?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this:

```
<?php printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br />',
esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
esc_html( $category->name )
);?>
```